# bpy.ops.uv.snap_selected fails

Tags: python

why does pack_islands work but snap_selected errors with incorrect context?

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT', toggle=False)

#Works
bpy.ops.uv.pack_islands(margin=0.05, rotate=False)

#No problem either
bpy.data.screens['UV Editing'].areas[1].spaces[0].image = bpy.data.images[imgName]

#Fails, context incorrect
bpy.ops.uv.snap_selected(target='PIXELS')
```

I've tried some workarounds, like that:

```
import bpy
bpy.context.area.type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'
bpy.ops.uv.snap_selected(target='PIXELS')
```

This changes the active viewport (usually a space 3d from where the code is run) to an image editor. It works, but I can't **set an image** here.

Update: I now found a solution to set an image to this area

```
bpy.context.space_data.image = bpy.data.images[imgName]
```

Still, my question remains, why is this necessary? Is there maybe a more elegant solution?

Comment: Stating the problems but not saying describing the background of what you are trying to achieve just makes a question harder to resolve. If you spend the time to describe what exactly you were trying to achieve, someone may come up with a solution that may look really different to the current one you are looking at.

Comment: My questions are basically 1.) Why is this necessary for snap_selected, but not for pack_islands? 2.) How to execute the bpy.ops.uv stuff properly without running into this problem and without this more or less ugly workaround?